# Google Sheets to Googel Calendar - Duplications

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar, duplicates

I've been reading a few questions and help on managing a google sheet then transferring info to google calendar via email.

I'm using the below code which i pulled from various places and its working really well however a couple of things i'm struggling with:

1. every time i run the script it duplicates the events, how do i stop this from happening every time the script is run - but still allow for say, addition of new email addresses down the line or update the calendar entry?
2. cant quite get the starttime and endtime to work nicely - the script is run off a tab in a google sheet that pulls its data from another tab (data entry)to make life easier for my users; is there a trick to the format for yyyy-mm-dd-hh:mm:ss?
3. possible to setup a line of code as part of this to send out automatic reminders say 7 days out from the event?

Appreciate any and all help on this!

Code thats working right now:

```
function CreateEvent() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange('***<LINKTOCELLTHATHASCALENDARID>***').getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('***CALENDARID<DELETED>***');
  var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lr);

  var count = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:F"+lr+"").getValues(); 

    for (x=0; x<count.length; x++) {

      var shift = count[x];

      var title = shift[0];
      var startTime = shift[1];
      var endTime = shift[2];
      var guests = shift[3];
      var description = shift[4];
      var location = shift[5];   
      var event = {
          'location': location,
          'description': description,
          'guests':guests +',',
          'sendInvites': 'True',
      }

      eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, event)
  }
}
```

Comment: Try keeping record of which ones you created in the spreadsheet and then don't use those again.

Comment: I don't quite understand what problem you are having with `startTime` and `endTime`. Could you provide more information on this? Maybe a sample of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information? That could be really useful to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
function CreateEvent() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId=sh.getRange('***<LINKTOCELLTHATHASCALENDARID>***').getValue();
  var eventCal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById('***CALENDARID<DELETED>***');  
  var drg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,7);
  var dA=drg.getValues(); 
  var crg=sh.getRange(2,7,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);//save that event was created in column G
  var cA=crg.getValues();
  for (i=0;i<dA.length;i++) {
    var shift=dA[i];
    var title=shift[0];
    var startTime=shift[1];
    var endTime=shift[2];
    var guests=shift[3];
    var description=shift[4];
    var location=shift[5];  
    if(!shift[6]) {
      var event={'location': location,'description': description,'guests':guests +',','sendInvites': 'True'}
      eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, event)
      cA[i][0]="CREATED";//keeps this event from being created again
    }
  }
  crg.setValues(cA);
}
```